# how to import data in monogo database .bson fiels

Tags: mongodb

I have mongo db dump which has

```
.bson
```

and

```
.json
```

files. How can i import this database in monodb through command line?

Answer (score 1):

Import a .bson file:

```
mongorestore -d db_name -c collection_name path/file.bson
```

For Json try this

```
mongoimport --db dbName --collection collectionName <fileName.json>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mongorestore to dump bson files, and use mongoimport to import json files.

Example:

> Mongo Restore (without Authentication)

```
mongorestore dump-2013-10-25/
```

> Mongo Restore (with Authentication)

```
mongorestore --host mongodb1.example.net --port 3017 --username user --password pass /opt/backup/mongodump-2013-10-24
```

> MongoImport (without Authentication)

```
mongoimport --db users --collection contacts --file contacts.json
```

> MongoImport (with Authentication)

```
mongoimport --host mongodb1.example.net --port 37017 --username user --password pass --collection contacts --db marketing --file /opt/backups/mdb1-examplenet.json
```

Refer: [Link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/)